# Adobe ASC 2.0 and ASDoc

Tags: actionscript-3, ant, compiler-construction, air, asdoc

After upgrading to the AIR 3.6 SDK which uses the new ASC 2.0 compiler all the ASDoc tasks in my Ant build files fail. I'm getting the error:

```
BUILD FAILED
E:\Projects\Eclipse\project\build\build_swc.xml:51: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Projects\Eclipse\projectbuild\build_swc.xml:209: Problem: failed to create task or type asdoc
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Did Adobe remove the ASDoc Ant task? I can't find any information about this elsewhere. ASDoc generation worked flawless before I installed the 3.6 SDK.

Comment: Check the documents for ant task changes; check your classpath; check the jars in the classpath of your taskdef and look for taskdef.properties or antlib.xml to see if the asdoc task has been renamed.

Comment: ASC2.0 doesnt understand MXML so that could be an issue (if youre using flex)

Answer (score 2):

Incompatibility issues with the new compiler may require you to download the AIR 3.6 SDK version that doesn't include ASC 2.0.  It, too, is available from the download site, although it's not immediately noticeable.

[image]

Comment: The bad thing is that if I download this package, my flex builder shows errors like "Could not create the view: Plug-in com.adobe.flexbuilder.as.editor was unable to load class com.adobe.flexbuilder.as.editor.ui.packageexplorer.FlexPackageExplorer." and nothing works. It feels like something is missing in this package. Everything used to work fine with 3.4 and I experienced same problems with 3.5 like now with 3.6.

Comment: appears the air sdk is indeed not complete. So you need to overwrite the old sdk with the new one without deleting old, so that missing files would stay. I just don't understand why all the instructions say that you should delete the old one completely.

Comment: Humm.  Typically you shouldn't need to overwrite the AIR SDK, but it's common when merging with the Flex SDK.  Are you using Flash Builder 4.7?  Wish i could help diagnose the problem, but I use Flashdevelop, which requires this download since it doesn't yet support ASC 2.0, and everything works fine.  The problem could be caused by a setting in Flash Builder.  You should post a new question.  There seems to be lots of problems with this new version.

Comment: I have this happen after I restart FB after clicking File > Restart. Restarting a second time and it goes away.