# AIR 3.6 + ASC 2.0 Produce White Screen in iOS Release Build

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

We're developing an AIR for iOS application currently. We upgraded to AIR 3.6 last week and have had issues with exporting release builds. Basically, you launch the app and see our launch image but then... nothing. Just a white screen.

ADL works fine, just not release builds. I have downgraded to 3.5 and, with no changes to the codebase at all, I was able to use the app with no issue.

Upgrade was simply backing up the previous SDK, and pasting the new SDK into the old SDK and replacing all the files (as is instructed). I also did as Adobe instructed and created an empty dir named "strip" within lib/aot/, but this has not helped the issue. We have experienced the issue after compiling on both Windows and OS X.

This is an ActionScript Mobile (not Flex) project built using FlashBuilder 4.7 by the entire team. Changing render mode (my first suspicion) does not fix the issue.

Does anyone have any insight into this issue? I've seen several posts in the Adobe forums saying similar issues but no solutions beyond adding the "strip" folder.

Comment: have you tried using the AIR 3.6 SDK without ASC 2.0?  if that works then the problem is likely caused by the new compiler.

Comment: That's a good idea. That download is not very apparent so I missed it. I'll try it in the morning and see if that works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 That worked. If you want to throw that into an answer, I'll mark it as correct for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*From Comment*]

Have you tried using the AIR 3.6 SDK without ASC 2.0? If that works then the problem is likely caused by the new compiler.

Comment: Can you explain what would be the procedure of "using the AIR 3.6 SDK without ASC 2.0"?

Comment: It's a separate download.  I posted a screenshot for this SO question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377944/adobe-asc-2-0-and-asdoc/15385548#15385548